# Using RPI, Pyfirmata, and Arduino to make a volt meter

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a volt meter using an rpi, pyfirmata and an arduino Uno.

I hooked it up and I have displayed the code below.
I am pretty sure that this should be working, however the readings that I get are very odd and very jumpy and inaccurate.
I have displayed the results also. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong... if theres a setting I need to change or something!?

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')  #Creates variable to connect to arduino board

analog_pin0 = board.get_pin('a:0:i') #Using Pyfirmata this code gets the value at pin A0

it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)  #starts iterator on board
it.start()

analog_pin0.enable_reporting() #Enable reporting of analog pins from arduino A0

time.sleep(1)

while True:
    reading0 = analog_pin0.read()
    if reading0 != None:
        voltage0 = reading0 * 5
        voltage0 = round(voltage0,2)
    else:
        voltage0 = float('nan')

    print(reading0)
    print(voltage0)
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
```

```
>>> %Run 'Radar Python.py'

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

0.219
1.09

0.0
0.0

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

0.0
0.0

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

28.2463
141.23

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

28.2463
141.23

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

0.219
1.09

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0

0.219
1.09

0.0
0.0

0.0
0.0

0.0
0.0

28.0274
140.14

0.219
1.09

28.0274
140.14

28.0274
140.14

0.0
0.0
```

as you can see, the numbers jump around significantly... this cant be right and something must be wrong

Comment: _I hooked it up_ How?

Comment: using the usb cable